# Como criar colunas dinamicamente com SQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou rodando um script que me retorna 250 valores que serão ***as colunas de um banco de dados.*** Eu preciso criar o banco de dados caso ele não exista ou simplesmente truncar ele e recriar todas as tabelas para atualizar colunas que venham a ser adicionadas futuramente. Tentei usar este código mas sem sucesso.

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=banco', $userdB, $passdB);
    foreach($res as $item){ 
        $sql = 'CREATE TABLE imovel ( '.$item["field"].' VARCHAR(300) );';
        $pdo->exec($sql);
    }
    $pdo = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Só para assegurar o entendimento, este `foreach` me retorna 250 valores que vão virar colunas do banco de dados. Rodo, não aparece erro mas também não cria a tabela com as colunas que vem do `foreach`.

Comment: Variaveis não são interpretadas dentro de aspas simples. Isso ai vai criar 250 tabelas `imovel`, não seria executar um `ALTER TABLE .... ADD COLUMN ...`

Comment: Fiz a correção concatenando o `field`. Ele cria o banco e coloca a primeira coluna. E depois para !!! Acho que o `CREATE` dentro do `foreach` não rola, mas então como?

Comment: Execute o primeiro create, e depois execute `ALTER TABLE` nos itens após este.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer o seguinte:

```
   $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=banco', $userdB, $passdB);

    foreach($res as $item){ 
        $sql .= $item['field']." VARCHAR(300),"; // O valor de $SQL sera "item VARCHAR(300),"
    }

    $sqlAux = trim($sql, ","); // Remove ultima virgula
    $pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE imovel (".$sqlAux.");"); // O valor sera "CREATE TABLE imovel (item VARCHAR(300),item2 VARCHAR(300),item3 VARCHAR(300),item4 VARCHAR(300));"
```

Talvez não seja o ideal, mas funcione.

Em ideia, iria armazenar todos itens e depois inserir todos de uma vez, entretanto, em questão de performance não sei dizer se seria eficiente, uma vez que seriam 250 item, mas, em um loop seria quase mesma coisa.